# How does this local var get assigned?

Tags: ida, stack-variables, local-variables

I'm using IDA PRO to disassemble a function, which produces a control flow that looks like this:

```
start_IE proc near

Buffer= dword ptr -230h
var_22C= byte ptr -22Ch
hFile= dword ptr -30h
hInternet= dword ptr -2Ch
szAgent= byte ptr -28h
dwNumberOfBytesRead= dword ptr -8
var_4= dword ptr -4
arg_0= dword ptr  8

;Do stuff that has nothing to do with ebp+var22C

mov     al, [ebp+var_22C]
jmp     short return

return:
mov     esp, ebp
pop     ebp
retn
start_IE endp
```

I've cut out a lot of irrelevant code, but *the only 2 times that var_22C appears in this procedure has been shown above*.

I'm having a difficult time finding out what value the data pointed to by var_22C will be since it's given no obvious assignment here.

Code before/after the function call in the caller:

```
mov     ecx, [ebp+var_C]
push    ecx             ; command char
call    start_IE
add     esp, 4
mov     [ebp+var_8], al
movsx   edx, [ebp+var_8]
test    edx, edx
jnz     short success
```

It only has 1 argument passed to it, which should be `arg_0`... We see that the return value from Var_22C is placed into `[ebp+var_8]` back in the caller afterwards.

Comment: show the code referencing `Buffer`.

Comment: Is it possible that there's a return value variable and it's simply uninitialized? What you're describing *is* producible from valid C code.

Answer (score 2):

probably the `Buffer` variable is accessed indirectly by one of the called functions and `var_22C` is actually part of the buffer.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can see this `mov     al, [ebp+var_22C]` command works with 8 bit data (according to name `al`), and there is a possibility that this `var_22C` variable is assigned as a part of bigger entity, for example as dword, which will require different offset.

I'd suggest to watch to stack accesses around this offset, specifically ,as @Igor Skochinsky says in comment, in a code related to `Buffer`.

Comment: Usually when thats the case, IDA will identify the byte is also accessed as a dword and will make all references to a dword.